# CakePHP main page displays 404 error

Tags: cakephp

I made many changes in views and img,css,js folders of my website. After all changes I'm receiving a 404 on the main page but all other pages works correctly. I'm using cakephp.

All day I'm trying to find what may cause this problem. I cleared the caches and log does not show the problem. How can I solve it?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. However, regarding change in views, may one think that you have changed the `home.ctp` file name while you turned off the debugging configurations of your CakePHP application.

Comment: I indeed changed also the main page (I chacked the bug still exists even if I restore previous version of the main page). Therefore the problem is not there. I did not change any file names.

Comment: Go to `app/Config/core.php` and check `Configure::write('debug', 2);` make sure its value is `2` as shown to be able to get meaningful error.

Comment: I'm receiving the list of 15-20 errors of this type:

Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/www/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 668
Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/www/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 668
etc.

but still it seems not to be the factor of the main problem

Comment: No this is the problem. To approve that, visit the other pages that did not give the 404 error, and you will not see those 15 errors.

Comment: Hmm you are right. But, debugger.php is not my page but it's directly from cakephp. How should I fix this bug comment?

Comment: WHAT changes in views and img,css,js folders ? Rename files, folders, move to other location ??? CakePHP version? PHP version?

Comment: The error does not occur in the debugger.php it is in your own code, the debugger.php role here is to regard the error only. You may called a non static object's method statically. i.e, as a general example, You may do `View::render()`  instead of `$this->render()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made any changes to app/config/routes.php?

You need to ensure the page your home location is connected to exists.

The line you may need to edit will be like this:

```
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

Check this first.

Comment: No changes in routes. All is as it was previously.

Comment: But you have changed the name of your home.ctp page to something else?

In which case you will need to update your routes.php to reflect this change.

Comment: No I did not. Above comment from @sємsєм helped me to fix the problem. I had old cakePHP and I updated PHP on the server. So the problem was not directly with the page. Sorry to bother you!

Comment: No problem - please mark the question as solved though. Thanks.